# callback problem-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using this [plug in](http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/). All works well, but now i need to make a change.
the callback always made the last condition - `else`, why?

this condition for example never works. Any syntax error?

```
($("#amount").val(value) == 400)
```

script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     jQuery("#SliderSingle").slider({
         from: 400,
         to: 2000,
         step: 200,
         round: 1,
         dimension: '&nbsp;€',
         scale: ['-400€', '600€', '800€', '1000€', '1200€', '1400€', '1600€', '1800€', '+2000€'],
         callback: function(value) {
             if ($("#amount").val(value) == 400) { //not working
                 alert("nop");
                 $(html("-400 sdf"));
             }
             else if ($("#amount").val(value) == 2000) {  //not working
                 alert("nopp");
                 $(html("+2000 dfs"));
             } else {
                 $(html(value)); //always working even if the value chosen is 400 or 2000
             }
         }
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want this:

```
function(value) {
    if (value == 400) {
        alert("nop");
        $(html("-400 sdf"));
    }
    else if (value == 2000) { 
        alert("nopp");
        $(html("+2000 dfs"));
    } else {
        $(html(value)); //always working even if the value chosen is 400 or 2000
    }
}
```

Although `$(html("-400 sdf"));` won't work. Unless you've defined a `html()` function

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
($("#amount").val() == 400)
```

with

```
$("#amount").val(value)
```

you are setting the value of #amount to the variable "value", which will return the element #amount again.

to do it within one line, you could use the following:

```
($("#amount").val(value).val() == 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are doing this:

```
if ($("#amount").val(value) == 400)
```

doing .val() returns the amount element, not the value you just set.

You *could* do this:

```
if ($("#amount").val(value).val() == 400)
```